# Props undefined using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to use redux to update hours, minutes and second in a script, but my props is undifined.

I use a fonction changeField, through my action, dispatched by my containers, and try to update my state with my reducer, but my initial props looks undifined. 
Error is the next : 
`Warning: Failed prop type: The prop`hours`is marked as required in`Start`, but its value is`undefined`.`

My component :

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
// import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// permet de faire fonctionner setInterval
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest function.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      const id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}


// début du component
const Start = ({
  setTime,
  hours,
  minutes,
  seconds,
  changeField,
}) => {
  const newTime = () => (
    new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
  );
  const heure = newTime();
  const [date, setDate] = useState(heure);
  const handleSetTime = () => {
    setTime(newTime());
  };
  useInterval(() => {
    setDate(newTime());
  }, 1000);

  // Ajoute la zone permettant de set sa propre heure
  const handleModifyTime = () => {
    document.getElementById('addTime').focus();
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(hours);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="start">
        <p> Heure du début de la réanimation </p>
        <p>
          {date}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="button-list">
        <button type="button" onClick={handleSetTime}>Commencer</button>
        <button type="button" id="changeHours" onClick={handleModifyTime}>Modifier l'heure de début</button>
      </div>
      <div id="addTime">
        <div>
          <p>Veuillez indiquer l'heure de début</p>
          <p>Format heure : minute : seconds</p>
          <form>
            <label htmlFor="hours">
              heure :
              <input type="number" placeholder="Heure" id="hours" name="hours" required size="2" lenght="2" value={hours} onChange={changeField} />
            </label>
            <label htmlFor="minutes">
              minutes :
              <input type="number" placeholder="Minutes" id="minutes" name="minutes" required size="2" lenght="2" value={minutes} onChange={changeField} />
            </label>
            <label htmlFor="minutes">
              secondes :
              <input type="number" placeholder="Secondes" id="secondes" name="seconds" required size="2" lenght="2" value={seconds} onChange={changeField} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Start.propTypes = {
  setTime: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  hours: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  minutes: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  seconds: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  changeField: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

My action.js

```js
export const SET_CATEGORY = 'SET_CATEGORY';
export const UPDATE_CATEGORY = 'UPDATE_CATEGORY';
export const SET_TIME = 'SET_TIME';
export const UPDATE_TIME = 'UPDATE_TIME';
export const CHANGE_FIELD = 'CHANGE_FIELD';

export const setCategory = (category) => ({
  type: SET_CATEGORY,
  category,
});

export const updateCategory = (category) => ({
  type: UPDATE_CATEGORY,
  category,
});

export const setTime = (time) => ({
  type: SET_TIME,
  time,
});

export const updateTime = (time) => ({
  type: UPDATE_TIME,
  time,
});

export const changeField = (value, name) => ({
  type: CHANGE_FIELD,
  value,
  name,
});
```

My container :

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Start from '../components/reaComponents/Start';
import { setTime, changeField } from '../actions/reanimation';


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  category: state.reanimation.category,
  initialTime: state.reanimation.initialTime,
  hours: state.reanimation.hours,
  minutes: state.reanimation.minutes,
  seconds: state.reanimation.seconds,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  changeField: (value, name) => {
    dispatch(changeField(value, name));
  },
  setTime: (initialTime) => {
    dispatch(setTime(initialTime));
  },
});

const StartContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Start);

export default StartContainer;
```

And finally my reducer

```js
import { SET_CATEGORY, SET_TIME, CHANGE_FIELD } from '../actions/reanimation';

const initialState = {
  reanimation: {
    category: '',
    initialTime: '',
    hours: '',
    minutes: '',
    seconds: '',
  },
};

const reanimationReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_FIELD:
      return {
        ...state,
        reanimation: {
          ...state.reanimation,
          [action.name]: action.value,
        },
      };
    case SET_CATEGORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        reanimation: {
          ...state.reanimation,
          category: action.category,
        },
      };
    case SET_TIME:
      return {
        ...state,
        reanimation: {
          ...state.reanimation,
          initialTime: action.initialTime,
        },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reanimationReducer;
```

Comment: Are you sure export const changeField = (value, name) => ({
  type: CHANGE_FIELD,
  value,
  name,
}); is receiving the right name, and value?

Comment: Also check `action.initialTime` you have in reducer `time: ...`

Comment: It looks like it receive nothing

Comment: Aha, so this is qhat you are getting undefined error. Did you check last suggestions?

Comment: Yeah it's the same

Comment: I can see the problem, will add an answer explaining it in a while

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onChange={changeField}`, try using this:

```
onChange={(e)=>changeField(e.target.name,e.target.value)}
```

I don't think it passes the right arguments when calling `onChange` the way you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 main problems.
You're reducer state is:

---

### First

```js
const initialState = {
  reanimation: {
    category: '',
    initialTime: '',
    hours: '',
    minutes: '',
    seconds: '',
  },
};
```

So `initialTime` is the property to modify the time right?

Look at here in your code:

```js
export const setTime = (initialTime) => ({
  type: SET_TIME,
  initialTime,
});
```

OR

```js
export const updateTime = (time) => ({
  type: UPDATE_TIME,
  initialTime: time,
});
```

---

### Second

In `EditForm`:

```js
<input ... onChange={changeField} />
```

Take a look at where this event is pointing to:

```js
export const changeField = (value, name) => ({
  type: CHANGE_FIELD,
  value,
  name,
});
```

You'll receive there an onChange event from input field  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

That means you receive and `event` object, not 2 params like (name and value) you 're expecting

What you could do is: i.e.

```js
export const changeField = ({ target: { name, value } }) => ({
  type: CHANGE_FIELD,
  value,
  name,
});
```

Hope it helps!